# Java class to java form

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In Netbeans it has the swing form editor for java,
I used to create a UI for my eclipse/maven project. But I'm having the issues of going in between both. Is there a better way to ingrate the project between the two IDE's?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use both Eclipse and Netbeans?

Comment: Well eclipse has some baseline features that netbeans doesn't have but netbeans has the nice form editor. I can't use all plugins with eclipse because of my company. I'm thinking I should just use netbeans for frontend and forget about eclipse.

Comment: If you can't use a plugin with Eclipse then it's worthwhile just using Netbeans. It's not the best IDE in the world, but it's form editor is pretty good.